# Utilizando o compomente DateTimePicker com Time

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-7

Estou utilizando o componente TDateTimePicker.

Coloquei na propriedade FORMAT o seguinte valor: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Em execução no form se não "clicar" no componente e mudar os valores, exemplo

```
21/09/2018 14:55:56 para 21/10/2018 20:55:56
```

ao capturar (DateTimePicker2.DateTime) o valor eu tenho 21/10/2018 14:55:56 por algum motivo a Hora "HH:mm:ss" o componente não atualiza.

Encontrei na internet o código, para colocar no OnChange do DateTimePicker:

```
var
 lEdit: TCustomEdit;
begin
 TDateTimePicker(Sender).DateTime := StrToDateTime(TCustomEdit(Sender));
```

Mas estou com o seguinte erro ao compilar:

```
E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'StrToDateTime' that can be called with these arguments
```

Comment: Qual seu objetivo ao pegar a Hora do TDateTimePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solte um `TDateTimePicker` e um `TEdit` no formulário e, em seguida, escreva os manipuladores de eventos da seguinte maneira:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DateTimePicker1: TDateTimePicker;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
    DateTimePicker1.DateTime:= StrToDateTime(Edit1.Text);
    // Você também pode usar TryStrToDateTime()
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DateTimePicker1.Format:= 'dd / MM / yyyy HH: mm: ss';
end;

end.
```

Para obter o erro, a função `StrToDateTime ()` espera uma `String` enquanto você passa um `TCustomEdit`. Você pode escrever se o `Sender` for `TEdit`

```
StrToDateTime(TEdit(Sender).Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou, apenas precisou colocar o `.Text`:

```
TDateTimePicker(Sender).DateTime := StrToDateTime(TCustomEdit(Sender).Text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Usando o metodo OnChange é bem tranquilo atualizar a hora

```
 procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1Change(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   DateTimePicker1.Time := Now;
 end;
```